# How to solve a nonlinear diffusion equation?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-equations, electromagnetism

Consider a thin film with a perpendicular applied magnetic field $H_a$ in $z$-axis. The nonlocal relation between $H_a$, the self-field $H_\text{self}$ (generated by the eddy current $J$) and the local magnetic flux density $B_z$ is given by :

$$B_z = \mu(H_\text{self} + H_a)\quad (1)\\
H_\text{self} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \frac{J(r')(r-r’)}{(r-r')^2} dr$$
that is Biot-Savart’s law in 2D with $r=(x,y)$.

One defines the local magnetization $m$ as : $J = \nabla\times m$.

As the Biot-Savart's law becomes highly singular when $r = r'$, one uses the Fourier transform. In fact, by inverting (1), one obtains

$$m = 2\mathcal{F}^{-1}[ k^{-1} \mathcal{F}(\mu B_z – H_a)]\quad (2)$$

where $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ are the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms and $k$ is the wave vector.

By increasing the applied magnetic field $H_a$, one can write the time evolution of the local magnetization as

$$\frac{dm}{dt} = 2\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[ k^{-1} \mathcal{F} \left(\mu  \frac{dB_z}{dt} – \frac{dH_a}{dt}\right)\right]\\
\frac{dB_z}{dt} = \nabla\times E \enspace ,$$
the Farady's law.

I think one can solve this diffusion equation using the weak form PDE interface in Comsol but I don’t know how to do it. However, I have no idea how to solve this in Matlab.

[Nonlinear diffusion equation](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.84.054537)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! Could you please typeset your math in MathJax (using LaTeX notation)? Your problem sounds interesting, and I suspect there are several potential methods for solving your problem, but I'm having trouble deciphering your equations.

Comment: My problem can be reformulated as following : Consider a thin film with a perpendicular applied magnetic field Ha in z-axis. The equation for the time evolution of the local magnetization (scalar variable) is : 
$\frac {dm(r,t)}{dt}$ = 2$\mathcal{F}^{-1} \{ k^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ $[\nabla. (|\nabla m(r,t)|\nabla m(r,t)) - \frac{dH_{a}(t)} {dt}] \}$
where $r$ = ($x$,$y$).
The calculation of the temporal evolution of the local magnetization is based on discrete integration forward in time : 
 
$ \frac {dm(r,t)}{dt} = \frac{m(r,t+\Delta t)- m(r,t)}{\Delta t} $ , at $t$ = 0, $m$ = 0.
Thank you !